# Many websites not opening from a certain WiFi connection

Tags: macos, network, wifi, internet, websites

My MacBook air is not opening many websites from my smart phones WiFi hotspot, it opens all from other WiFi's and my smart phone's hotspot opens all in other laptops. It shows that the sites can't be reached for them after trying to establish a secure connection in chrome, it is same for other browsers like safari.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues in past and suspect this is because of the WiFi connection.

It is most likely an issue with the Router's/Modem's MTU size settings and not necessarily because of an issue with your MacBook Air.

There are many helpful links online on what settings you can try with. One which might give you some insight is here- https://serverfault.com/questions/70075/why-does-lowering-the-mtu-from-1500-to-1499-allow-me-to-access-most-websites

A quick suggestion could be to compare the MTU settings of a working router with those of the non-working one.